# MongoDB cant start encrypted server

Tags: mongodb, rest, encryption, terminal, public-key-encryption

I keep receiving this error when i try to start the server encrypted:

```
iMac:~ User$ mongod --enableEncryption --encryptionKeyFile  /data/encryrest/mongodb-keyfile
2016-09-28T08:43:06.120-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=50483 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=iMac.local
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: enterprise 
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-09-28T08:43:06.121-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { security: { enableEncryption: true, encryptionKeyFile: "/data/encryrest/mongodb-keyfile" } }
2016-09-28T08:43:06.139-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-09-28T08:43:06.139-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=6G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),extensions=[local=(entry=mongo_addWiredTigerEncryptors)],encryption=(name=AES256-CBC,keyid=".system"),
2016-09-28T08:43:06.140-0700 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] It looks like the data files were previously encrypted using an external key with id .DS_Store. Attempting to use the provided key file.
2016-09-28T08:43:09.336-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (-31802) [1475077389:336536][50483:0x7fff7d80e000], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: unable to read root page from file:WiredTiger.wt: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2016-09-28T08:43:09.336-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1475077389:336604][50483:0x7fff7d80e000], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: WiredTiger has failed to open its metadata
2016-09-28T08:43:09.336-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1475077389:336632][50483:0x7fff7d80e000], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: This may be due to the database files being encrypted, being from an older version or due to corruption on disk
2016-09-28T08:43:09.336-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1475077389:336664][50483:0x7fff7d80e000], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: You should confirm that you have opened the database with the correct options including all encryption and compression options
2016-09-28T08:43:10.136-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2016-09-28T08:43:10.136-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error, terminating
2016-09-28T08:43:10.136-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
iMac:~ User$
```

Im on a Mac OS X and assuming the issue is coming for WiredTiger. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: which `operating system` are u using ? and have u change `mongo database engine

Comment: Im using Mac OS X. How do I change the mongo database engine?

Comment: I check my storage engine with this "db.serverStatus().storageEngine" and "name" : "wiredTiger" was returned. Is this the database engine?

Comment: yes mongo default engine is wiredTiger.

Comment: i think your database is corrupted .try this and then start service

Comment: `db.runCommand( { repairDatabase: 1 } )`  try this

Comment: I ran that command. Now when I start the server Im seeing this error message "Unable to retrieve key .system, error: There are existing data files, but no valid keystore could be located."